# Excel, combining 2 tables

Tags: excel-formula

thank you in advance for taking time to look at this.

I am trying to merge / combine 2 tables in excel;-

the 1st table contains sales info of items sold in the month, there may multiple sales of same item sold on different dates.
the 2nd table contains bill of materials for each item. 
the common factor between the 2 tables being an item code.

What I would like to see is a combination of the 2 tables, for each of the items sold in table, listed underneath it are the bill of materials.

I have tried to upload a picture - shown below this text

[image: please see image for how i want to how to combine to tables in excel]

Comment: will it always be 3 mats for each item or will the numberof mats vary per item?  Also did you mean to have all items to have the same number in table 1? And since you have shown no formulas or code, what have you tired so far?

Comment: Vic - from my knowledge of Excel I can't see how to do this with a formula alone. It would be a fairly simple VBA method to do this. Do you have any VBA experience?

Comment: Hi Kevin,Thank you for taking the time to look at this. I do have experience with VBA, but cannot get my head around this one, any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Ed, Thank you as well for looking at this. There may be numerous mats in table 2 for different items, not just 3 as in my example, apologies for any confusion.